# where I can find contact_size() function

Tags: gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[In tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=sensors&tut=contact_sensor&ver=1.9-4.0), there is a set of code shown below:

```
void ContactPlugin::OnUpdate()
{
  // Get all the contacts.
  msgs::Contacts contacts;
  contacts = this->parentSensor->GetContacts();
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < contacts.contact_size(); ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "Collision between[" << contacts.contact(i).collision1()
              << "] and [" << contacts.contact(i).collision2() << "]\n";

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < contacts.contact(i).position_size(); ++j)
    {
      std::cout << j << "  Position:"
                << contacts.contact(i).position(j).x() << " "
                << contacts.contact(i).position(j).y() << " "
                << contacts.contact(i).position(j).z() << "\n";
          std::cout << "   Normal:"
                << contacts.contact(i).normal(j).x() << " "
                << contacts.contact(i).normal(j).y() << " "
                << contacts.contact(i).normal(j).z() << "\n";
      std::cout << "   Depth:" << contacts.contact(i).depth(j) << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder where I can find the **API information about usage and definition of contact_size() function.**
I am not familiar with C++, is it because related to C++ library?
Any hint or guide would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16295/where-i-can-find-contact_size()-function/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

#### Protobuf intro

Gazebo messages are generated using Protocol buffers (protobuf). The messages are described in `.proto` files, and Protobuf uses that file to generate a C++ class.

For example, [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/bae84f76b4ad7a6a7cecaeb3e76e545b8c8d5f3e/gazebo/msgs/contacts.proto?fileviewer=file-view-default) is the description for the contacts message:

```
import "contact.proto";
import "time.proto";

message Contacts
{
  repeated Contact contact   = 1;
  required Time time         = 2;
}
```

You can see that the `contact` field is a `repeated` field of the `Contact` (singular) message. For every repeated field, Protobuf generates a `<field_name>_size()` function, such as the `contact_size()` one.

This is all described in the [Protocol Buffers C++ Generated Code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#repeatedmessage) documentation.

#### Header files

This is not ideal, but personally, what I do when I want to check a message's API, is to check its header files (who has time to read the protobuf documentation? :P).

Protobuf creates a `<message_name>.pb.h` header for each message and installs it in your system. You can look for the `contacts.pb.h` header like this:

```
find /usr | grep contacts.pb.h
```

Then you'll find something similar to this:

```
/usr/local/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/msgs/contacts.pb.h
```

So you can open that file and take a look at the API:

```
gedit /usr/local/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/msgs/contacts.pb.h
```

Digging through header files is definitely not ideal... We do have some form of message API documentation, but that's broken, as described on [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2153/message-api-documentation-broken) issue.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on 2017-05-26**:
Thanks for your quick, helpful and considerate reply!